# Can Custom Workflows be created without Designer?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, office-integration

I have have to create a custom workflow for SharePoint 2010, however we are blocked from using Designer, and have MS Office 2007 not 2010. Is there a way to create a custom workflow any other way? Can it be done in Visio 2007 or InfoPath 2007?

Answer (score 1):

No custom workflows cannot be deployed/installed to SharePoint using Visio or InfoPath. If you have already created reusable workflow using SharePoint designer, you can save it as a template, go to Site Assets library and save it as a WSP package.

The WSP can then be installed as a Farm or Sandboxed solution in the target environment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Unfortunatley the only workflows i currently have are the OOTB workflows. I will have to look into what else i can do... although i feel as if though i've read somewhere that Visio 2010 integrates nicely with SP 2010 when it comes to creating workflows... but again i dont have Visio 2010 at work either, trying to see if maybe they"ll upgrade my office install if this does work since designer has been disabled

Comment: Workflows authored in Visio 2010 still needs to be imported into SharePoint Designer and be converted to something SharePoint can understand.

Comment: If SPD is not allowed, you may want to look at K2 or Nintex for browser based workflow configuration.